# AWS S3 batch operation gets access denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created the following bucket policy in the source bucket

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "kvmweivdgd",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/cfn-batch-copy-role"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObjectTagging",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::sourcebucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The following policy is attached to the destination account's IAM role

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "E28BGI8FL0HF59",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObjectVersionTagging",
                "s3:PutObjectTagging",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObjectTagging",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::destinationbucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::sourcebucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::manifestbucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::jobreportbucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But yet the AWS S3 batch operation throws access denied. Any ideas on what might be the problem here

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach the following trust policy to the IAM role to allow the Amazon S3 batch operations service principal to assume the role.

```
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Principal":{
            "Service":"batchoperations.s3.amazonaws.com"
         },
         "Action":"sts:AssumeRole"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Sorry could you be more detail

Comment: I mean, I would like to know if the problem is only with batch operations. so I suggest to try on an instance with that Role attached to just get an object from the sourcebucket and see if also has a problem with permissions

Comment: Actually the batch role works with some accounts but not with every account. While comparing the accounts it has the same configurations but the batch fails in one and works with the other

Comment: mmm honestly I don't have more idea, just in case check the policy spelling maybe there is a typo, but not sure why doesn't work then